# How do I stop floating the number keypad on Galaxy Note 8.0?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, text-input

My Galaxy Note 8 displays a floating numeric keyboard when the inputType is number. How do I make it stop floating? It doesn't happen for other inputTypes, just this one. There's no option to change it to "normal" like there is with the regular keyboard. The only buttons are 0-9, delete, next, and a gear button.

I'm using Android version 4.4.2.[image]

Comment: Why is it a problem for you? If it accepts numeric values, then the numbers are sufficient, isn't it?

Comment: It blocks buttons in my application when it's not docked.